# Translation Selector in TYPO3 TCA (V 8.7)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a major issue in finishing my plugin. In versions under 8, I have had a dropdown in my custom TCAs to select the language, located above the action buttons on the top. The following code had worked:

```
    'languageField'            => 'sys_language_uid',
    'transOrigPointerField'    => 'l10n_parent',
    'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
```

Neither the database changed, nor have I made major changes to the TCA (except those described in the upgrade tutorial), but under TYPO3 8, I am not able to have the select with the different languages shown again. Do you have any idea, why?

Many thanks
Stephan

Comment: Does your showitem configuration contains the field? Could you edit your post to add the showitem configuration? Did you upgraded from an older TYPO3 version? Maybe you have to check if you have to migrate/update your TCA. A good starting point is to compare any TYPO3 core TCA table configuration.

Comment: I am not missing the field in my TCA itself, more i am missing the field for language selection over the save button